# Angular highcharts is returning error trying to draw a histogram

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm trying to implement [this histogram using highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/histogram-series) and [highcharts-angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular). I implemented both libraries and got the "Hello World" chart working.

But as soon as I try to change its chart type to `'histogram'`, I get the following error pointing to the `series` object:

```
Type '{series...}' is not assignable to 'SeriesOptionsType'.
Type '{series...}' is not assignable to 'SeriesParetoOptions'.
```

Hello World:

```
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3],
      type: 'line'
    }]
  };
...
}
```

**Changing chart type, where the error is occuring:**

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
      data: [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4]
      type: 'histogram',
      xAxis: 1,
      yAxis: 1,
      baseSeries: 1
    }]
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: *as soon as I try to change its chart type*... what was the chart type, and what did you change it to?

Comment: @R.Richards You're right, should've stated it more clearly. From the hello world's type `'line'` to `'histogram'` - see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the implementation of a histogram is a little bit different like mentioned in the [docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/histogram-series#how-to-create-a-histogram)

> The histogram requires the following module modules/histogram-bellcurve.js.
>
> The histogram series is a column series with no padding between the columns and with self-setting data. Unlike most other Highcharts series, the data property is not available - it is set internally based on the base series data (more precisely y values of the data).
>
> Two steps are required to create an Histogram chart:
>
> Set the series type to histogram 2. Set baseSeries to the right data series’ id or index.

in your angular-project this means :

**1. you need to import the histogram-bellcurve module in your component:**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
import HC_histogram from 'highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve';
HC_histogram(Highcharts);
```

**2. unlike the other charts there is no data property, so the config has two parts.**

```
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
      type: 'histogram',
      xAxis: 0,
      yAxis: 0,
      baseSeries: 1
    },
      {
      type: 'line',
      data: [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4],
      id: '1',
      visible: false,
      showInLegend: false
    }]
  };
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this kind of works. But how do I get rid of the line and use the data solely for the histogram filling the whole graph?

Comment: you can add visible:false and showInLegend: false , so that the data-series is completely hidden. Is this what you meant? (i've changed the example above)

Comment: This somehow display only three bars. I want to achieve something like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/Histo.png/375px-Histo.png - looking at bars and different widths, is this even possible?

Comment: maybe, have a look at binsNumber and binsWidth , https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.histogram.binsNumber .